# Native url in deep link

Tags: deep-linking

Is native prefix and url transformations are same or differ for each devices (such as android , ios, ipad, etc).

I want the sample deeplink example for single app which has links for multiple devices (android, ios, ipad)

Answer (score 0):

They are the same for both Android and iOS if the app developer made both apps similar.
An example would be a deeplink to a facebook profile:

```
fb://profile/1234567890
```

This should work on both Android and iOS.

Visit these pages for reference:

- [Publishing App Links](http://applinks.org/documentation/)
- [URIs and Your Mobile App](https://www.sparq.it/web/api/v1/docs/mobile_uris)